# Firebase Hosting. Firebase Deploy only deploys index.html

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a small website with 3 different html pages. I am trying to host with firebase. When I run `firebase deploy` in the target directory, the only page that gets hosted is `index.html`. If I click a link on the website to navigate to one of the other pages, I am navigated to a `404 page`.

All pages are located within my public directory.

Here is my firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I get firebase to host the other html pages?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase hosting uses case-sensitive URLs.